# If I created a store of user stories. Is there a way to fetch the name of the parent program's name associated with a story

Tags: rally, code-rally

So far I have only been able to reach the parent one step up, in this case the name of the feature.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, in general hierarchy is limited to 2 levels in a single response.  There are some shortcuts here and there though, depending what you need.

If you fetch both `Feature` and `Parent` I think that will give you the feature's parent info.  You can't go any higher than that in one request though...